# MFA Security Question - Really Opinion Based?

Tags: discussion

In asking the below question regarding MFA authentication and what it prevents against in the context of Salesforce, I'm not sure I understand why this was marked as opinion based.

Particularly because this question was derived from a topic on the Identity and Access designer architect exam. Out of the options provided, the Salesforce exam designers apparently thought 3 of the attacks were more likely to be prevented than the others.

[What types of attacks does Salesforce Multi Factor Authentication (MFA) prevent?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/311466/what-types-of-attacks-does-salesforce-multi-factor-authentication-mfa-prevent?noredirect=1#comment464009_311466)

If this is opinion based because of the better vs. defined answer I suppose the closure makes sense, but hard to think the exam answers could be argued as a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 3):

I agree there is a factual basis which can be used to answer which types of attack are *not* protected. I have therefore reopened your question.